# How to align widgets to top in Column class?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Which parameter should I change to fit the values fom "childen :  [...]" to the top in UI? (Currently they are filling all free spase in the Container).
Thank you in advance for explanation!!
Code snippet:

```
return new Container(
  child: new Column (
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,


    children: <Widget>[
      new Text('\$$priceUsd\n'),
  new Text('1 hour: $percentChange1h%',
    style: new TextStyle(
        color: changeColor),


    )],
  )
);
```

[image]

Comment: Try wrap them in an `Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: ...)`

Comment: use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start`

Comment: Thank you all, guys, but problem was in Text argument, for some reason I didn't delete "\n" , so it made a blank string after first text...

Answer (score 9):

just set the main axis alignment to the start

```
return new Container(

  child: new Column (
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,


    children: <Widget>[
      new Text('\$$priceUsd\n'),
      new Text('1 hour: $percentChange1h%',
        style: new TextStyle(color: changeColor),
    )],
  )
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all, Raouf, but problem was in Text argument, for some reason I didn't delete "\n" , so it made a blank string after first text...